# Collapsed div flashing when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#my-container")
  .each(function() {
    var ol = document.createElement("ol");
    ol.setAttribute("id", "anchor-navlist");
    $("#anchor-navigation").append(ol);

    var h2 = $("h2", ".node__content");

    h2.each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      var addId = text.replace(/\s/g, "-");
      $(this).attr("id", addId);
      $(this).attr("class", "anchor");

      $("<li/>")
        .append(
          $("<a />", {
            text: text,
            href: "#" + text.replace(/\s/g, "-")
          })
        )
        .appendTo("ol#anchor-navlist");
    });

    $("#anchor-navigation .heading, #anchor-navlist li a").click(function() {
      if ($("#anchor-navigation").hasClass("closed")) {
        $("#anchor-navigation").removeClass("closed");
      } else {
        $("#anchor-navigation").addClass("closed");
      }
    });
  });

function handleScroll() {
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrolling) return;

  if (windowTop > 50) {
    $("#anchor-navigation").addClass("closed");
    scrolling = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrolling = false;
      $("#anchor-navigation").removeClass("closed");
    }, 2000);
  }
}

var scrolling = false;
$(window).scroll(handleScroll);
```

```css
#my-container #anchor-navigation {
     max-width: 942px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: sticky;
     top: 10px;
     background: #e8e8e8;
     padding: 10px;
     z-index: 100;
}
 #my-container #anchor-navigation .heading {
     cursor: pointer;
}
 #my-container #anchor-navigation .heading h2 {
     font-size: 20px;
     margin-top: 5px;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
}
 #my-container #anchor-navigation ol {
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
 #my-container #anchor-navigation.closed ol {
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="my-container">
  <div id="anchor-navigation" class="">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2>Explore this page</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="node__content">
    <h2 id="Heading-1" class="anchor">Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.
      Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem.</p>

    <h2 id="Heading-2" class="anchor">Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Vestibulum ac
      diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</p>

    <h2 id="Heading-3" class="anchor">Heading 3</h2>
    <p>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Nulla porttitor
      accumsan tincidunt.</p>

    <h2 id="Heading-4" class="anchor">Heading 4</h2>
    <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia
      eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

I am trying to create a floating nav at the top of my page containing anchor links to the content in the page.

The nav will be open on page load and will close on scroll down the page > 200 and reopen when scroll back to top. The nav will also open or close based on click.

Currently if I scroll the nav it will close, clicks are also working. However, if I scroll and then click outside the window or focus on devtools, for example there is a flash of the closed menu on the screen. I believe it is being caused my timeout function.

The opening and closing of the div is being controlled by adding/removing a class "closed" on a given selector. I can see in inspector that the class is being removed on scroll but the timeout is then trying to re-add it each time and so causing the flash (but only when the window is blurred?), I believe that it shouldn't be doing this because it will hit the return first.

Comment: Could you please add a full working snippet to the question, including all relevant HTML, CSS and JS, so that we can see a working example of the problem.

Comment: Looking at your code, when the window scrolls down you close the nav, but then 2s late open it again?   Seems odd on its own.

Comment: Your issue is quote possibly because you don't clear out the `setTimeout` and scroll events fire *a lot* - so you have 100s of setTimeouts running, possibly in the middle of you scrolling (if you keep scrolling).   You should *probably* clearInterval before starting another setTimeout - unclear if that would fix the issue you're currently describing, but looks like it would be an issue.

Comment: I was a little confused by *"should to that as it should hit the return first"*  - I guess that's an attempt to stop what I've just described above?    However, there's no check/return *within* the setTimeout.  so that will always run (which was the confusing part).

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. I've updated the question with a working snippet and the problem exists there. I think the issue may be a combo of using both CSS and jQuery to control the behaviour of hiding/showing and not constructing my timeouts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use clearTimeout. It's possible that clicking to expand won't work - replacing the sticky position with fixed could solve this.

```
var timeout;

function handleScroll(event) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowTop > 200) {
            $("#anchor-navigation").removeClass("closed");
        } else {
            $("#anchor-navigation").addClass("closed");
        }
    }, 100);

}

$(window).scroll(handleScroll);
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, this does indeed work with position: fixed but unfortunately that won't work for the design I require. Do you know why the click works for fixed and not sticky?